# How do I add a decimal point between the first 9 digits and the last 2 digits?

Tags: php, regex

How do I add a decimal point between the first 9 digits and the last 2 digits in the value that is being pulled in at line:  `$matchesLine[$key] = substr($line,166,11);` ? As, the fetched values do not contain a decimal point.

Sample Data

Input: `00023659819`

Desired output: `#########.## >> 00236598.19`

Script provided by @Shlomtzion

```
<?php


$text = "I0023540987805R01  ABC                         GHI                       OLirrt                 000000000000000100EA 0812160070451700   1098833   1990041300000001086000000000108600000000000996000000000032100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006589000000000000000                                     P0012B    
0000002032902R01  DEF                         JKL                       KLijuI                 000000000000000100EA 0812160070451700   1029132   1997010800000002396000000000239600000120002326000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004560000000000000000000000000987600000000                                     A203SD   ";

echo '<pre>';
$txt = explode("\n",$text);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($txt);

foreach($txt as $key => $line){
    $subbedString = substr($line,2,11);

    $searchfor = '02354098780';
    //echo strpos($subbedString,$searchfor); 
    if(strpos($subbedString,$searchfor) === 0){
        $matches[$key] = $searchfor;
        $matchesLine[$key] = substr($line,166,11);
        echo "Found in line : $key";
    }

    
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($matchesLine);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know that there are 11 digits, you can use [substr_replace](https://www.php.net/substr_replace)

```
$str = "00023659819";
echo substr_replace($str, ".", 9, 0);
```

Output

```
000236598.19
```

If you want to do the replacement when 11 digits, you can use [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with 2 capture groups for 9 and 2 digits and in the replacement use the 2 capture groups with a dot in between `$1.$2`

```
$str = "00023659819";
echo preg_replace("/^(\d{9})(\d{2})$/", "$1.$2", $str);
```

Output

```
000236598.19
```

Comment: thank you. btw, what does this do: "$1.$2"?

Comment: @JackYuan `$1` and `$2` point to the value of the capture group in the replacement. In the pattern, this part `(\d{9})` is capture group 1 and this part `(\d{2})` is capture group 2.

Comment: @JackYuan I have updated the answer to do the replacement on the resulting string of 11 characters that you get from using `substr`

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to this via `preg_replace`:

```php
$input = "00023659819";
$output = preg_replace("/(?=\d{2}$)/", ".", $input);
echo $output;  // 000236598.19
```